# How to delegate functionality or design to other UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

For example, I have two same buttons in all view controllers. And reaction of these buttons are the same in all view controllers. How I can make this functional in common class and use this class or object in every view controllers?

Comment: and does my graphic appear correctly in inherited view controllers? (if graphic is created in Interface Builder)

Comment: is the reaction corresponded to the same viewcontroller from which it is fired.

Comment: Yes, it appears correctly but maybe you want to take care of the actions in another class if the 2 ViewControllers do different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the couple target/action to the button, you can set the target to a specific class:

```
[button1 addTarget:myOtherClassInstance action:@selector(doSomethingAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button2 addTarget:myOtherClassInstance action:@selector(doSomethingAction2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and in the myOtherClass.m

```
- (void)doSomethingAction:(id)sender {
//Do something and maybe check the sender
}

- (void)doSomethingAction2:(id)sender {
//Do some other thing and maybe check the sender
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I can make my graphic in common class?

Comment: In this case, you should create a separate VC for the component with the 2 buttons (let's call it buttonsVC). In the main VC, you reference the buttonsVC and in mainVC viewDidLoad, [mainVC.view addSubView:buttonsVC.view]. It's the first step of the integration, have a look at this article for more info about VC life cycle and VC container :http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.ch/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html

Comment: Can I have several VCs on one View Controller?

Comment: Yes, you can. I edited my previous comment with a link for info about this

Answer (score 1):

you can put the action method in the delegate class , and link the button tap event to this method like this 
 `[yourButton addTarget:yourDelegate action:@selector(yourmethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`